# JQuery .load() followed by .css() modification

Tags: javascript, jquery

I seem to be encountering some kind of synchronicity issue. In the head of my pages, I am loading in a navigation intoa `<nav>` then attempting to modify it on a case to case basis, e.g. an `<a id="bio">` within it, like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("nav").load("/components/nav.html");
    $("#bio").css("color", "var(--magenta)"); <!-- #bio is inside nav.html, which has been loaded -->
});
```

This loads, but the `.css()` does not take place. **Sometimes** it will work exactly once, but when I hard refresh the page it is back to being unmodified.

Comment: The second parameter of `.load` is a callback function and is "executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed" - [jQuery load function](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) is an *asynchronous* operation.  If the second operation is dependent upon that asynchronous operation completing, it needs to happen it a callback:

```
$(function(){
  $("nav").load("/components/nav.html", function(){
    $("#bio").css("color", "var(--magenta)");
  });
});
```